# Having a problem with my scapy port scanner using sys.argv

Tags: python, scapy

This is for my python class, I'm trying to make a port scanner that can scan TCP ports when the user enters an IP address, address range or domain on PowerShell.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import sys

from scapy.all import*

if len(sys.argv) < 1 or "-help" in sys.argv:
    print('''
 Welcome to the port scanner

    To use this program enter a IP address, address range or domain.
    And it must also be used in CLI or Powershell
    
    How to use this program:

    Enter the destination IP, address range or domain into
    the CLI or Powershell window
    

               ''' )
    sys.exit()

# User inputs an IP address, address or domain into a CLI or Powershell 
destIP = Net(sys.argv[1])
# Ports that will be scanned: 
# 21 - FTP
# 22 - SSH
# 23 - Telnet
# 25 - SMTP
# 53 - DNS
# 80 - HTTP
# 110 - POP3
# 135 - Windows RPC
# 137 - Windows NetBIOS over TCP
# 138 - Windows NetBIOS over TCP
# 139 - Windows NetBIOS over TCP
# 443 - HTTPS
# 1433 - Microsoft SQL Server
# 1434 - Microsoft SQL Server
# 8080 - HTTP Alternative
PortRange= [21,22,23,25,53,80,110,135,137,138,139,443,1433,1434,8080]



# If user inputs one value this if statement will execute
if len(sys.argv) == 1 in sys.argv:
    for destPort in PortRange:
        # Source port is randomized using the random module from port 1025 to 65334. 
        srcport = random.randint (1025, 65534)
        ans = sr(IP(dst=destIP)/TCP(sport=srcport, dport=destPort),timeout=2,verbose=0)
        # If there is not answer from the port scanned the program will print
        # The port is filtered
        if ans == None:
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is filtered.")
        # If the port scanned give answers with a SYN ACK the program will print
        # the port is open
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == "SA"):
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is open")
        # If the port gives an answer but resets the connection
        # the program will print the port is closed.
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == "RA"):
             print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is closed")
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == "R"):
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is closed")

#If user inputs 2 values or -verbose this elif statement will execute
if len(sys.argv) == 2 in sys.argv :
    for destPort in PortRange:
        # Variable used to when user enters verbose into the sys.argv
        variVerbose = 1
        srcport = random.randint (1025, 65534)
        # verbose is equal to 1 to show user the packets being sent.
        ans = sr(IP(dst=destIP)/TCP(sport=srcport, dport=destPort),timeout=2,verbose = variVerbose)

        if ans == None:
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is filtered.")
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == "SA"):
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is open")
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == "RA"):
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is closed")
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == "R"):
            print(f"{destIPs}:{destPort} is closed")
```

The problem I'm having is when I enter an address nothing happens, but my help dialog works when I enter -help. Have I missed anything? or did something wrong?

Comment: In general you should try using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module to handle command-line flags. At first it might look more complicated but if you use it for most simple cases you'll write much less code (and less buggy code) for handling your command-line interface, so you can focus on more interesting things like the port scanner itself.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1 in sys.argv:
```

Just remove the `in sys.argv`. Not sure why you put that there. You just want `if len(sys.argv) == 1:`

Same with the similar line below it. These will always evaluate to False.

The expression `len(sys.argv) == 1` is a boolean expression. It will always resolve to either the value `True` or the value `False`. So the overall expression is either `if True in sys.argv` or `if False in sys.argv`. This is always going to be false because the `in` operator asks if the value on the left side is contained in the list (or other collection type) on the right-hand side. `sys.argv` is a list of strings, so this is definitely false.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code. The code does nothing because all the `if` that checks input arguments are wrong. For example:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1 in sys.argv:
```

Should be:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
```

The sys.argv always have the path of the script you are running so, the len of sys.argv at least is 1.
Also, check your variable names, because `destIPs` does no exist.

I fixed all the code (only the part when only 1 ip is set as input):

```
import sys
import random
from scapy.all import Net, sr, sr1
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP

if len(sys.argv) < 1 or "-help" in sys.argv:
    print('''
 Welcome to the port scanner

    To use this program enter a IP address, address range or domain.
    And it must also be used in CLI or Powershell

    How to use this program:

    Enter the destination IP, address range or domain into
    the CLI or Powershell window


               ''')
    sys.exit()

# User inputs an IP address, address or domain into a CLI or Powershell
destIP = Net(sys.argv[1])
# Ports that will be scanned:
# 21 - FTP
# 22 - SSH
# 23 - Telnet
# 25 - SMTP
# 53 - DNS
# 80 - HTTP
# 110 - POP3
# 135 - Windows RPC
# 137 - Windows NetBIOS over TCP
# 138 - Windows NetBIOS over TCP
# 139 - Windows NetBIOS over TCP
# 443 - HTTPS
# 1433 - Microsoft SQL Server
# 1434 - Microsoft SQL Server
# 8080 - HTTP Alternative
PortRange = [21, 22, 23, 25, 53, 80, 110, 135, 137, 138, 139, 443, 1433, 1434, 8080]

# If user inputs one value this if statement will execute
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    for destPort in PortRange:
        # Source port is randomized using the random module from port 1025 to 65334.
        srcport = random.randint(1025, 65534)
        tcp_connect_scan_resp = sr1(IP(dst=destIP) / TCP(sport=srcport, dport=destPort, flags="S"), timeout=10)
        # If there is not answer from the port scanned the program will print
        # # The port is filtered
        if tcp_connect_scan_resp is None:
            print(f"{destIP}:{destPort} is filtered.")
        elif tcp_connect_scan_resp.haslayer(TCP):
            # If the port scanned give answers with a SYN ACK the program will print the port is open
            if tcp_connect_scan_resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12:
                send_rst = sr(IP(dst=destIP) / TCP(sport=srcport, dport=destPort, flags="AR"), timeout=10)
                print(f"{destIP}:{destPort} is open.")
            # If the port gives an answer but resets the connection the program will print the port is closed.
            elif tcp_connect_scan_resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x14:
                print(f"{destIP}:{destPort} is closed.")
```